# SQL How do you check if there are any timestamps that are within one hour range between each other

Tags: sql, timestamp, calculation

I have a table that looks like below where user events are recorded as unixtime

```
select day, 
user_id, 
unixtime,
from_unixtime(unixtime)
from sampletable
```

| day | user_id | unixtime | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-20 | 1 | 1608434879 | 2020-12-20 03:27:59.000 |
| 2020-12-20 | 1 | 1608468153 | 2020-12-20 12:42:33.000 |
| 2020-12-20 | 2 | 1608436224 | 2020-12-20 03:50:24.000 |
| 2020-12-20 | 2 | 1608437616 | 2020-12-20 04:13:36.000 |
| 2020-12-20 | 3 | 1608476189 | 2020-12-20 14:56:29.000 |
| 2020-12-20 | 3 | 1608505424 | 2020-12-20 23:03:44.000 |
| 2020-12-20 | 3 | 1608505438 | 2020-12-20 23:03:58.000 |
| 2020-12-20 | 4 | 1608463622 | 2020-12-20 11:27:02.000 |

and I want to check the number of users with events that are within one hour between each other.

For example,

- user1 doesn't count as his two events are 9 hours and 15 mins apart.
- user2 counts as his two events are within 1 hour range between each other.
- user3 also counts. Although his first event and second event are 8 hours and 7 mins apart, his second and third events are 14 seconds apart.
- user4 doesn't count as this user performed only 1 event.

I want my final result to look like either:

| day | total_user | number_of_qualified_user |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-20 | 100 | 60 |
| 2020-12-21 | 123 | 82 |
| 2020-12-22 | 196 | 10 |
| 2020-12-23 | 111 | 28 |
| 2020-12-24 | 119 | 103 |

or

| day | percentage_of_qualified_user |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-12-20 | 60.00% |
| 2020-12-21 | 66.67% |
| 2020-12-22 | 5.10% |
| 2020-12-23 | 25.22% |
| 2020-12-24 | 86.55% |

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Tag your quesiton with the databse you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lead()`:

```
select day, 
       count(distinct case when next_unixtime - unixtime < 60*60 then user_id end) as num_users
from (select t.*,
             lead(unixtime) over (partition by user_id, day order by unixtime) as next_unixtime
      from sampletable
     ) t
group by day;
```

For the ratio, you would divide by `count(distinct user_id)`.